# Check if there data for a sub Model in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel with two Models in it.  In the View I want to see if there is any data in the Model:

```
@if (Model.MyModel1 == Empty) { do something }
```

But I can not figure out how to do this.  When I remove this check the View works fine, I can display data from the models (when there is data) with no issues.  I spent yesterday and half a day today trying a lot of different approaches I found on the web but none of them worked and none of them talked about ViewModels, only single Models, so I wonder if that is my issue.  I have tried:

```
Model.MyModel1.Any()
Model.MyModel1.AsQueryable().Any()
Model.MyModel1[0].value1 == ""
Model.MyModel1 == null 
Model.MyModel1.IsEmptyOrNull()
```

More and more along these lines..

I get two types of errors, the first is when I try using a function like `Model.MyModel1.Any()`
I get:

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<MyThing.Models.MyModel1>' does not contain a definition for 'Any'
```

When I try something like `Model.MyModel1[0].value1 == null` I get:

```
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<MyThing.Models.MyModle1>'
```

The ViewModel is:

```
namespace MyThing.ViewModel
{
    public class combinedModel
    {
        public IQueryable<MyModel1> MyModel1{ get; set; }
        public IQueryable<MyModel2> MyModel1{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

When there is no data the Controller uses this code:

```
        var combinedModel = new combinedModel();
        combinedModel.MyModel1 = Enumerable.Empty<MyModel1>().AsQueryable();
        combinedModel.MyModel2 = Enumerable.Empty<MyModel2>().AsQueryable();
        return View(combinedModel);
```

Comment: Why are you using `IQueryable<>` as the model type? Why not `IEnumerable<>`?

Comment: @Andrei The code I posted for the Controller is only a small part of all of the controller code.  Most of time the controller is returning a query result to the View.  I have an `if` statement that does a quick check to see if there might be query results, if there in no chance that there will be results it runs the code segment I posted speeding things up since I don't have to wait for the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my situation it seems that, as Xiaoy312 pointed out, I can not use Extension Methods in my View for some unknown reason.  While I believe his answer is correct (and may be preferred way) to do this it did not work for me so I am posting what did work in case anyone else has the same issue with Extension Methods.  I would read Xiaoy312 answer and comments before trying this approach.

To check if there is data in your Model, without using Extension Methods in your View, you can use:
`(Queryable.Count(Model.MyModel1) < 1 )`

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your first try, `Model.MyModel1.Any()`. However, it tests if the sequence has any element, so you want to negate that result to know if it is empty or not.

```
@if (!Model.MyModel1.Any()) { do something }
```

Comment: I have tried that and get the `RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<MyThing.Models.MyModel1>' does not contain a definition for 'Any'` error

Comment: Make sure you have included the namespace `System.Linq`, as [`IQueryable<T>.Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343630(v=vs.100).aspx) is clearly there.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I don't understand what you mean, I am not a .Net programmer by trade.  I have `using System.Linq;` in the Controller but no reference to it in the View.  Should I be somehow adding it to my View, and if yes how?

Comment: You need to add this line on the top `@using System.Linq`

Comment: Thanks for the info but that did not work plus it added the text "using system.Ling" at the top of my webpage.  I took a hint from you and started drilling trough namespaces and came up with `(Queryable.Count(Model.SylesUSA) < 1 )` that seems to work.  I have no clue why it does.

Comment: @Mrphin That's strange. It seems like the extension methods aren't working for you, and can only be used as static method.

Comment: Any ideas how I might have done this?  A setting or command?  I used the provided Web Application template as the base for my project and have removed (what I thought) was unnecessary.  I am still using the slightly modified _layout.cshtml